# Android has stopped Unfortunately

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an application which should record video and capture image and I in 'onCreate' function 
wrote this code

```
myCamera = getCameraInstance();

myCameraSurfaceView = new MyCameraSurfaceView(this, myCamera);
myCameraPreview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camPreview);
myCameraPreview.addView(myCameraSurfaceView);
```

Video recording works as need.

I have another button which should open browser and for this I write this code

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://www.novoda.com"));
startActivity(viewIntent);
```

When I click the button browser opens but when I want to exit browser occurred the following error 'Unfortunately has stopped'

When I make comment this code `myCameraPreview.addView(myCameraSurfaceView);` everything works well...

Comment: please add your logcat file associated with the crash.

Comment: Is there an onResume override? You could be setting the camera or camera preview to null in the onResume.